Casting in Shadow Projection form
I have this long and tiring discussion with a friend who claims that casting in Shadow Projection form requires Silent Spell and Still Spell metamagics because "show me where it's written that shadows can do verbal and somatic components".
I am certain he just read some random discussion on Reddit or Paizo forums claiming such but I need a definitive answer.
The way I understand it, all I need is Amulet of Grasping Souls so that I can use my material components that I wouldn't be able to touch otherwise (on top of getting my Christmas Tree of magic items on me, because otherwise it would be a very sad casting anyway). As for somatic and verbal components polymorph rules regulate that. Has hands? Can do somatic. Has mouth? Can do verbal. And shadows have those.
Context: 100% RAW answers, no 3pp, no RAI.

Added links to spell and item.

What you mean by dysfunctional? Isn't it just incorporeality buff, so to speak? Also why second paragraph specifically? It just reads like usual polymorph spell series paragraph to me.

@NecXelos  What's 3pp?

3pp = Third Party Product

Technically, shadows are incapable of language
The System Reference Document (SRD) for Dungeons & Dragons 3.5 and from which Pathfinder takes many of its rules includes in its shadow entry this statement: "Shadows cannot speak intelligibly" (q.v. Monster Manual 221). Pathfinder excludes this statement from its Pathfinder Bestiary entry for the shadow (245).
However, Pathfinder added to creature stat blocks a Languages entry. (Cf. The SRD that puts a creature's languages in the creature's description, like the gnoll and worg.1) But the Pathfinder Bestiary entry for the shadow just doesn't have a Languages entry. The Pathfinder Bestiary explains this absence in its Stat Blocks section: "[I]n cases where a line in a stat block has no value, that line is omitted" (5).
In this regard, the shadow et al. joins a handful of other Int 6 creatures that lack a Languages entry in their stat blocks, like the wolf-in-sheep's-clothing (Pathfinder Bestiary 3 285), the festering spirit (Pathfinder Bestiary 4 98), and the cytillipede (Pathfinder Bestiary 5 65). The shadow is an outlier in both possessing an Intelligence score sufficient to employ language and lacking language, but it's not a unique outlier.2,3,4
This is important because the caster of a spell that possesses verbal components "must be able to speak in a strong voice." A clear indicator that a creature can deliver verbal components is the creature having a Languages entry in its stat block, or its description saying it can generate spellcasting-like noises. A creature that doesn't have a Languages entry or an appropriate description—like a shadow—can "speak in a strong voice" only at the GM's discretion.
Hence, if the goal is to use in the largest number of campaigns a character who employs the shadow projection spell as an ersatz magic jar effect so that the character can cast spells while in his own shadow, then it's probably safest to take the feat Silent Spell just in case the GM rules that shadows can't deliver verbal components.
Technically, a GM may rule that shadows lack hands sufficient for spellcasting
The SRD in its glossary entry on Spells included this:

A spellcasting creature that lacks hands or arms can provide any somatic component a spell might require by moving its body. Such a creature also does need material components for its spells. The creature can cast the spell by either touching the required component (but not if the component is in another creature’s possession) or having the required component on its person. Sometimes spellcasting creatures utilize the Eschew Materials feat to avoid fussing with noncostly components. (q.v. Monster Manual 315)

Text like this is absent from the Pathfinder Bestiary. Thus a GM may rule that a shadow cannot execute somatic components because shadows, in the GM's opinion, can't perform the necessary "measured and precise movement of the hand," perhaps going so far as to rule that a shadow's ghostly appendages aren't really hands at all. That ruling may seem farfetched, but it'd apparently be the ruling of the asker's friend.
So if the goal is a character that's playable in the largest number of campaigns, then it's probably best to take the feat Still Spell—again, just in case.
The polymorph rules are unhelpful here
The transmutation subschool Polymorph, in part, says

While in such a form, you cannot cast any spells that require material components (unless you have the Eschew Materials or Natural Spell feat), and can only cast spells with somatic or verbal components if the form you choose has the capability to make such movements or speak, such as a dragon. Other polymorph spells [like undead anatomy I et al.] might be subject to this restriction as well, if they change you into a form that is unlike your original form (subject to GM discretion). (Emphasis mine.)

Such a form is a creature that possesses the type animal, dragon, elemental, magical beast, plant, or vermin. The shadow that's given independent life and mobility by the spell shadow projection possesses the type undead, therefore inviting the GM's discretion. How "unlike your original form" is your own shadow? Only the GM can say.
Also, it can be viewed as an overreach to apply these rules at all to the shadow projection spell that both is a necromancy spell (not a transmutation spell) and doesn't itself change the caster's form (instead, "you infuse your life force and psyche into your shadow").

On the other hand, casually…
I am keenly aware that the asker is uninterested in matters of opinion, the question being concerned with a strict reading of the rules alone. Nonetheless, I believe it would be a disservice to other readers that have less strict policies to exclude the following additional—although unofficial—rulings by one of the game's representatives.
James Jacobs addresses these issues
Creative Director James Jacobs in his long-running Q&A column here calls it "weird" that shadows are "missing their language line. They should be able to speak Common." Jacobs—who helped develop Dungeons & Dragons 3.5—offers no more information about the topic, which is disappointing.5
Also, here (and, by extension, here) Jacobs says that creatures that can cast spells can cast their spells, no matter their natural number, kinds, or arrangement of appendages.
Then James Jacobs addresses shadow projection
Here is the following exchange in that same Q&A thread between a fan and Jacobs:


[A user] wrote:
…[C]ould shed some light on how this spell [i.e. shadow projection] operates (but not too much, given the spell in question!).

Can you perform verbal and somatic components whilst a shadow?
Can you access your feats and use spell-like or supernatural abilities whilst you are a shadow?
Can you even speak whilst you are a shadow?
Do you use your own stats, only your mental stats or none of your own stats when you are a shadow?


The answer to all these questions is more or less no. When you cast this spell, you basically "turn off" your character and "turn on" a shadow, as detailed in the Bestiary. You'd still use your own skills (not modified by the shadow's stats) and your own hit points, but the rest is pretty much "just use the shadow stat block." It's meant to mostly be a scouting out an area spell first and a fighting spell second.


Notes
1 You now know that worgs have their own language. Forever. You won't forget this. Unfortunately, this knowledge will never be important. I blame Tolkien. You should, too.
2 I didn't check creatures with different Intelligence scores to see how many of them lacked a Languages entry. I'm sure it's a number. Searching for absence is a lot more intense than just searching for Int 6.
3 Creatures that lack a Languages entry are different from creatures that possess languages that they can't speak. The game makes clear this distinction in stat blocks like those of the giant eagle and howler.
4 The Pathfinder product Undead Revisited addresses none of these issues in its chapter on shadows (46–51). The Sample Shadow therein does, indeed, cast spells, but it has the template shadow lord (Pathfinder Bestiary 4 238–9), making it quite unlike the Pathfinder Bestiary shadow.
5 I was disappointed, anyway. I don't think any Monster (or Monstrous) Manual for Dungeons & Dragons clearly indicates that regular ol' undead shadows can speak, so I wanted Jacobs to say where he pulled that from. Maybe talking shadows are setting-specific?

Suggestions for improvement welcome.

Quick things to consider/possibly add or remove. Polymorph deals with undead forms too, spell series is called Undead Anatomy I-IV (IV being the one allowing incorporeal forms). The fact you infuse your own shadow also means that the shadow is exactly shaped as yourself with details such as fingers being there, thus invalidating the "incapable appendages" issue and moving the spell even closer rules-wise to polymorph ("you're as you were + things"). James Jacobs answers are strictly RAI plus he also said Shadows should have Common language in their statblock effectively invalidating himself.

@NecXelos 1) The polymorph subschool rules deal with undead by leaving how to deal with them up the GM; the existence of the undead anatomy spells doesn't change those rules. 2) Where did you find rules for infusing? 3) Please read the introductory paragraph before the quotations from James Jacobs (beginning "I am keenly aware…"); I said that part wasn't for you. ;-) Thank you for taking the time to respond.

I commented on James Jacobs parapgraph for the, broadly understood, posterity. This guy is as unreliable as it gets. He consistently contradicts himself, comments on random questions on Paizo forums without ever thinking about implications of his "answers/clarifications" and creates more confusion than there were in the first place. PF1 community would be better of if he never spoke at all. And others who find this topic should be aware of that, even if they are looking for RAI approach.


I don't see how not having a language affects spellcasting even verbal spellcasting, except for language-dependent spells.  You don't "cast spells in Common."
Ruling that incorporeality would make someone not able to conduct somatic components runs afoul of every single incorporeal spellcaster in the game and is pretty ridiculous.
Material components would be the only sticking point I'd see.



Fair. The point is that animals lack language and casters need special dispensation to cast as an animal. Having a languages entry enables but, you're right, it's lack doesn't, by strict RAW, disable casting. Will fix. 2. Incorporeality isn't the problem, and this answer never calls it one, not mentioning incorporeality at all. 3. The asker has (ahem) handled the incorporeal material components unless the GM rules that shadow "hands" are incapable of manipulating components.


Well, the shadow projection spell description itself doesn't mention any restrictions on spellcasting. It states, "You gain the shadow subtype..." It doesn't say you lose any abilities, only that you gain the shadow subtype.
Also there's no rule stating that having only natural attacks prevents spellcasting. Many creatures with only natural attacks (claws, bites, etc.) can still cast spells.
So your reasoning is correct. The shadow projection spell grants you a shadowy body with a semblance of a mouth and hands. The polymorph rules don't negate your ability to perform verbal and somatic components just because the form is shadowy. There's no RAW stating that shadows can't perform these components. Your friend's challenge to "show me where it's written that shadows can do verbal and somatic components" is a flawed argument. The burden of proof lies in finding a rule that prevents it, not the other way around.
To wrap it up - no, Silent Spell and Still Spell are not required to cast spells while under the effects of shadow projection. The spell doesn't restrict spellcasting, your shadowy form retains the ability to perform verbal and somatic components, and the Amulet of Grasping Souls addresses the material component issue. Your friend's interpretation is based on a flawed understanding of the rules. He's adding restrictions that simply aren't present in the RAW.
